# Data migration from MS Dynamic 2011 to Salesforce

Tags: data-migration

How to migrate the data from MS Dynamic 2011 CRM to Salesforce? is there any API? Please help me on this.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I'd like to take a moment to invite you to read about what's on topic ([help/on-topic]). Specifically, we don't do product recommendations here. If you want help, consider asking about two or three specific products and/or features, so as to narrow down the scope of the question in a way that allows a potentially objective answer.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thank you for your reply. And, i have updated my question. Can you please help me

Comment: Data migration is a huge subject - in simple terms it is a case of map the Dynamics Data Model to Salesforce then deal with the issues identified, such as missing fields, different formats, picklist values, etc. Then extract all the data into a compatible format like .csv and then load it. There is not a specific API for migration. This is far too broad for a question here. please see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the data, it might be as simple as exporting the data as a CSV, then using the [Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_import_wizard.htm&type=5), or slightly more complicated, by way of the [Apex Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5). Both tools require the data in particular formats, which you can read about in the related help topics for each of the above links.

If that ends up being too complicated, you might start looking on the AppExchange. As long as you can get the CSV data, there are lots of options on the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=data%20import). Please note that you'll need to do your own research here, as we don't do product recommendations.

Finally, doing a simple search on the internet for "migrating dynamics crm data to salesforce" should yield a lot of useful results. For example, there are some applications that can connect to both systems and act as a two-way bridge for the data. There are various costs (usually subscription-based or volume-based), so you will need to do research for the product(s) that suit your needs and are within your budget.

There is no "one right way" to do migration, and what works for me or someone else might not work for you, so if you do decide to purchase/subscribe to a service, make sure you research a few alternatives first. It is entirely possible to migrate all your data for free, but the Data Import Wizard and Apex Data Loader takes some time to learn and get used to; if you just want to "get it done," you're probably going to have to pay someone for the service.